# Printing HTML via JS after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have 3 PHP pages.

- Page1 is the page that the user is viewing.
- Page2 is included on Page1, this list items and has a delete button beside each item.
- Page3 is my parsing file that I send info to via AJAX to update my DB
  without leaving/refreshing the page.

My JS where I send all of my data to my 3rd PHP file is like so:

```
$(".delete").bind("click", function() {
    var id = event.target.id;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);

            //document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'deleted';
            //$("#message").html('deleted');
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "page3.php?delete="+id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
});
```

This works fine and I can see what is being returned in the console, but I can't add the message. The message div is located on page2.

The only reason I can think of that this might be happening is because page2 is being included in page1, although the div exists in the DOM and I don't get a JS error in the console saying the div can't be found.

Comment: If your markup is correct I don't see any reason why the div#message wouldn't be altered. Is it perhaps hidden through the `zIndex`, `display`, or `visibility` properties?

Comment: @zfrisch thanks for your comment, No I was actually inspecting the element to make sure. After doing some testing it works when the message div is on page1 so I think it must be something to do with how it is included.

Comment: Is there more than one element with the same id? How is page2 included in page1?

Comment: @epascarello thanks for your comment, no there is only one div with that id. It is included like so: `<?php include_once("page2.php"); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved with a little redesign and putting the div on page1.

Still not entirely sure why it will not work on an included page but that was definitely the cause.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing check that page has loaded

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'deleted';
}
```

OR

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#message").html('deleted');
});
```

Comment: No this isn't the case. My entire JS is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){...}` including the whole function above

Comment: Next suggestion - Make sure the message div is visible.

Comment: See previous comments

Comment: I mean. The message is being written but you cannot see it because the element containing the message is hidden.